# opencv stereo correspondence "OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to compute depth using stereo correspondence but keep getting the error in the title of this question. I don't really know how to debug this.

Code:

```
        void imageprocess::get_depth()
        {
            Size size = bridge[0]->image.size();
            Mat imgl, imgr, disp;
        
            cvtColor(bridge[0]->image, imgl, CV_RGB2GRAY, 1);
            cvtColor(bridge[1]->image, imgr, CV_RGB2GRAY, 1);
        
            CvStereoBMState* state = cvCreateStereoBMState(0, 16);
            cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM(&imgl, &imgr, &disp, state);
            cvReleaseStereoBMState(&state);
        
            imshow(WINDOWM, disp);
            waitKey(3);
        
        }
```

Unless my C++ is a lot rustier than I thought, I think I'm using the functions correctly. Which is why I don't see any problem with my code.

It works fine without:

```
cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM(&imgl, &imgr, &disp, state);
```

and the function decleration is:

```
cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM(const CvArr* left, const CvArr* right, CvArr* disparity, CvStereoBMState* state)
```

**Edit:**
I also tried from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027574/convert-cvmat-to-const-cvmat-or-cvmat:

```
    Size size = bridge[0]->image.size();
    Mat imgl, imgr;

    cvtColor(bridge[0]->image, imgl, CV_RGB2GRAY, 1);
    cvtColor(bridge[1]->image, imgr, CV_RGB2GRAY, 1);
    
    CvMat cvimgl, cvimgr, cvdisp;
    
    cvimgl = imgl;
    cvimgr = imgr;
    
    CvStereoBMState* state = cvCreateStereoBMState(0, 16);
    cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM(&cvimgl, &cvimgr, &cvdisp, state);
    cvReleaseStereoBMState(&state);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56815/opencv-stereo-correspondence-%22opencv-error:-bad-argument-(unknown-array-type)-in-cvarrtomat%22/) by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved. All the arguments to the function must be of the same type CvMat apparently. And cvdisp in the edit wasn't created properly.

---

Originally posted by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) with karma: 172 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0